# Android NumberPicker OR AlertDialog with Single choice?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, numberpicker

I need to have a dialog that I can choose a time duration (30,60,90,120, ... seconds). I have two choices ( I don't use Spinner )

1. Using **NumberPicker inside Dialog** and the list of displayed labels are:

   ```
   30 Seconds
   60 Seconds
   90 Seconds
   120 Seconds
   150 Seconds
   180 Seconds
   ...
   ```
2. Using **AlertDialog with Single choice** ( RadioButton will be displayed in dialog)
3. **My question is:**

   ```
   Which kind of Dialog do you recommend?
   ```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I would use a dialog since it's the most easier action for a user to do.

but it's a totally personal opinion and you should do what's best for you and your UX :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for AlertDialog, its simple to implement.

```
AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog, null))
    .create();
```

In order to listen for user events

```
View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog, null);
Button btn = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.the_id_of_the_button);
btn.setOnClickListener(your listentener);
AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setView(view)
    .create();
```